# Swagger does not recognize JsonPropertyName introduced by .net core 3.0

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

We had WEB API on .Net Core 2.2 with configured swagger and the following model:

```
public class ProjectCreateDto
{
    [JsonPropertyName("project_id")]
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("goods_ids")]
    public long[] GoodsIds { get; set; }
}
```

Recently we moved to .Net Core 3.0 and now we use System.Text.Json.Serialization and it turns out that swagger seems like not supporting newly introduced JsonPropertyName. This is very critical for all who use our API. So instead ***project_id*** I have ***projectId***. Is there any workaround to make compatible swagger and new serialization? Thank you.

Comment: you can try NewtonSoft Json

Comment: @SushantYelpale I used it before moving to 3.0. But I had to choose System.Text.Json because all my intragration tests failed and AddNewtonsoftJson() didnt do the trick while new serialization works quite well, swagger generates scheme ignoring attributes

Comment: It seems like a known issue of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore:  https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1280